# update angular2-fullcalendar after ngAfterViewInit

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

Alright, this is something new and I haven't got it answered in any threads related to angular2-fullcalendar.

I am able to compile what is said and written on this documentation of [angular2-fullcalendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-fullcalendar)

Problem occurs when i am trying to populate calendar with my events, after the view has been initialised.

Scenario 1:

1. View Loads
2. Shows Calendar
3. Events are displayed(hard-coded)

Scenario 2:

1. View Loads
2. Shows Calendar
3. getting records(from server)
4. Asked angular2-fullcalender to update my view.
5. No error, nor the events are displayed.

HTML:

```
<angular2-fullcalendar [options]="some" id="mycal" #mycal></angular2-fullcalendar>
```

Working example: Scenario 1

```
event: any[] = 
          [{
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2017-02-21',
            end: '2017-02-22'
          },{
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2017-02-16T16:00:00',
            end: '2017-02-17'
          }];
calOptions: Options = {};
ngOnInit() 
{
 this.some.events = this.event;
}
```

Not working example: Scenario 2

```
event: any[] = 
          [{
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2017-02-21',
            end: '2017-02-22'
          },{
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2017-02-16T16:00:00',
            end: '2017-02-17'
          }];
ngOnInit() { this.getBookings(); }

getBookings() {

        this._service.getEvents().subscribe(values => {

this.updateCalendar();

}, () => console.log('error'))

updateCalendar()
    {
this.calOptions.events = this.event;
      //$(this.element.nativeElement).fullCalendar('updateEvents',this.event) //I tried doing the query way too, but it failed.
    }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Thats the problem, there is no error! The calendar is not being updated once i keep them after the server call!

Comment: Where do you call `updateCalendar`?

Comment: @yurzui thanks for the reply. I am calling it in `getBookings()`, updated Scenario 2. Thanks.

Comment: It works for me. I will make a plunker

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/DicnkFVFhpEwJlRFMnOY?p=preview But i was wrong i used `addEventSource`. And i thing you don't need this package because it's just wrapper

Comment: It solved! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1: NPM Install

`npm install fullcalendar`

`npm i angular2-fullcalendar`

`npm install jquery`

`npm install moment`

### 2: Remove `angular2-fullcalendar` from `node_modules` and place it under `app` folder

### 3: Open `Systemjs.config.js` Add the below snippet end `map` section.

```
'moment': 'npm:moment',
'jquery':'npm:jquery/dist/jquery.js',
'fullcalendar':'npm:fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js'
```

I have attached the file below for reference purpose only.

### 4:  Open `app.module.ts` import `CalendarComponent` from `angular2-fullcalendar`

```
import { CalendarComponent } from './angular2-fullcalendar/src/calendar/calendar';
```

Add the `CalendarComponent` to declarations array.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [
    CalendarComponent
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
```

### 5  Now its time to display the calendar. Pick your own component. For example, I will take `booking.component.html`

```
<angular2-fullcalendar [options]="calOptions" id="mycal" #mycal></angular2-fullcalendar>
```

In `booking.component.ts`

```
import { Options } from 'fullcalendar'
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as moment from "moment
```

Import the 3 things, now u see the importance the `systemjs.config.js` that we did earlier.
Contniue with `booking.component.ts` in the class,

```
@ViewChild('mycal', { read: ElementRef }) myCal: ElementRef;
```

From the step 5 beginning, there is `#mycal` in the html, that is `'mycal'` in the above statment.

```
calOptions: any = {};
```

Initialising the calOptions to be empty, remember not null.

```
Contructor()
{
var events = [ {
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: '2016-09-01'
        },
        {
          title: 'Long Event',
          start: '2016-09-07',
          end: '2016-09-10'
        }];
this.UpdateCalendar(events);
}

UpdateCalendar(events)
{
this.calOptions.events = events
$(this.myCal.nativeElement).fullCalendar('addEventSource', events)
}
```

In the above, in constructor we have some events to be displayed, we are calling updateCalendar to update the events.

More references to this: https://gist.github.com/shah-smit/85aff341cd4a20494910ab2c17e82777/edit

Comment: That worked like charm. Made my day. 2 week of wait. had finally ended.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [implementation](https://github.com/nekken/ng2-fullcalendar/blob/master/src/calendar/calendar.ts) of that npm package you will see it is very basic. I would advise wrapping full calendar in your own Typescript, and handling the FullCalendar events and entry points yourself, that way you can take advantage of the entire [API](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/).

The component below is one I have used with success, that uses JQuery.

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Overlay } from 'angular2-modal'; 
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'fullcalendar';
import { Options } from 'fullcalendar';
import _ from 'lodash';

export interface IEvent {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    start: Date;
    end: Date;
    type: string;
    backgroundColor: string;
    textColor: string;
    className: string;
    borderColor: string;
}

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'calendar',
    template: `<div id='calendar'></div>`
})
export class CalendarComponent {

    @Input('height')
    public height: number;

    @Output('event-click')
    eventClick = new EventEmitter();

    @Output('month-changed')
    monthChanged = new EventEmitter();

    @Output('date-change')
    dateChange = new EventEmitter();

    calElement = null;

    addEvents(events: IEvent[]) {
        this.calElement = $('#calendar');
        if (!_.isNil(events)) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
        }
    }

    getCurrentMonth() {
        const currentdate = <any>$("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate');
        return currentdate.month();
    }


    ngOnInit() {
        this.calElement = $('#calendar');
        let clickFunc = function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            this.eventClick.emit(calEvent);
        };

        let eventRender = function (event, element) {
            const args = {event: event, view: element};
            this.dateChange.emit(args);
        };

         let viewRender = function (view, element) {
            this.monthChanged.emit(view.intervalStart.month());
        };

        let boundRender = eventRender.bind(this);
        let boundClick = clickFunc.bind(this);
        let boundView = viewRender.bind(this);

        let options: any = {
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay listMonth,listWeek,listDay'
            },

            defaultView: 'month',
            aspectRatio: 1,
            eventRender: boundRender,
            eventClick: boundClick,
            viewRender: boundView
        };

        if (this.height > 0) {
            options.height = this.height;
        }

        this.calElement.fullCalendar(options);
    }
}
```