# Angular 2 FullCalendar:Unexpected value CalendarComponent in a module

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar-2

I am implementing calendar events using [ng2-fullcalendar](https://github.com/nekken/ng2-fullcalendar),i installed `npm install angular2-fullcalendar --save` and followed all steps to import

Calendar.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgaModule } from '../../../theme/nga.module';
import { ValidationService } from '../../../services/validators/validation.service';

import { Calender } from './calender.component';
import { routing } from './calender.routing';

import { CalendarComponent } from "angular2-fullcalendar/src/calendar/calendar";


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        NgaModule,
        routing,

    ],
    declarations: [
        Calender,
        CalendarComponent
    ]

})
export default class CalenderModule { }
```

But still it showing unexpected value CalendarComponent error from angular2-fullcalendar,please help me.

Comment: What error are you facing ? Please post stacktrace.

Comment: @user3145373ツ Error showing browser `"EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected value 'CalendarComponent' declared by the module 'CalenderModule'
Error: Unexpected value 'CalendarComponent' declared by the module 'CalenderModule'
    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (https://]exam.com/vendor.bundle.js:15775:27)"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42473743/update-angular2-fullcalendar-after-ngafterviewinit

Comment: @user3145373ツ: i tried.but i am using webpack.config instead of systemjs.config file..i am not getting what changes i have to do webpack.config.ts

Comment: I think you do not need to make changes in `webpack.config.js`, just try again with `npm cache clean` , `npm install` then see what happen !

Comment: @user3145373ツtried.everything is perfect in webpack.config.js file locally..but getting same error while deploying..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153677/discussion-between-pramod-ramadand-and-user3145373-).